# Extremal points relative to origin for an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Suppose I have an ellipsoid of the form

$ax^2 + by^2 + az^2 - cxy -cyz = d$

How would I find the points nearest to, and furthest from, the origin?

Comment: The ellipsoid is rotationally symmetric about the $y$ axis, so... it's either on the $y$ axis, or on the "equator" relative to it.

Comment: @Fundamental It's symmetrical in $x=z$ isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I see it's not rotational symmetry. Well, one approach is to look for critical points of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ on the surface. At a critical point, the gradient of $f$ is parallel to the gradient of $ax^2 + by^2 + az^2 - cxy -cyz$. The Lagrange multipliers...